# Database Error Unknown column, codeigniter 3 Php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

can someone help me please. I have no more idea about how to fix this error:
**Error: Unknown column 'table_book.year' in 'field list'**.
I have a model to retrieve data from my database, and I have created function to retrieve data using inner join clause, the idea of this function is to retrieve all published books from table_book,  on the table_book have a column named **id_autor**, this **id_autor** it's the primary key of another table named table_autor.
I want to retrieve the autor_name from table table_autor by retrieving the data from table_book joining the column **id_autor** that both of table has in comun.

**MY CODE**

**Model**

```
function retrieveBook($id_book = null) {
    
    $this->db->select('table_autor.name as name, table_book.year, table_book.tittle, table_book.file');
    $this->db->from('table_autor');
    if($id_book != null){
        $this->db->join('table_book', 'table_autor.id_autor = table_book.id_autor');
        $this->db->where('table_book.id_book', $id_book);
    }
    
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if ($this->db->error()) {
        $error = $this->db->error();
        echo 'Error: '. $error['message'];
    }

    echo '</br>';
    echo $this->db->last_query();

    return $result;
}
```

**Controller**

```
function indexBooks(){
    $data = array(
        'retrieveBook'        => $this->Retrieve->retrieveBook(),
    );
    $this->load->view('library/indexBooks', $data);
}
```

**View***

```
<?php if($retrieveBook):?>
                            <?php
                        
                            foreach($retrieveBook->result() as $key=>$bookItem):?>
                                <tr>
                                    
                                    <td><?=$bookItem->name?></td>
                                   
                                     <td><?=$bookItem->tit?></td>
                                    <td><?=$bookItem->year?></td>
                                    <td><?=$bookItem->file?></td> 
                                </tr>  
                             <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php endif;?>
```

Schema for **table_book**

```
CREATE TABLE `table_book` (
  `id_book` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_autor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_bookCatalogo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `capa_livro` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `autor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `edicao` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `nr_serie` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `editora` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `local_publicacao` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `nr_pagina` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `exemplar` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `abstract` text NOT NULL,
  `adicionado` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci COMMENT='onde sera os registros dos livros da biblioteca';
```

grateful for the attention

Comment: Can you show the schema for `table_book`? The error is saying the column doesn't exist on the table itself.

Comment: Also, you're calling the `retrieveBook` function without an argument. Without the `$id_book` argument that function is not doing the join to the `table_book` table, but you're still trying to select columns from that table. You probably want to move this `if($id_book != null){` down one line, so that only the `where` clause is inside the `if` statement.

Comment: **@aynber** I've added the schema for table_book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was why it threw that error:

```
 if($id_book != null){
        $this->db->join('table_book', 'table_autor.id_autor = table_book.id_autor');
        $this->db->where('table_book.id_book', $id_book);
    }
```

You only join table_book table when you have value of `$id_book`. So when you `retrieveBook`:

```
$this->Retrieve->retrieveBook(),
```

In this case, the column 'table_book.year' will not exists.
To fix that, just left join that table all the time:

```
function retrieveBook($id_book = null) {
    
    $this->db->select('table_autor.name as name, table_book.year, table_book.tittle, table_book.file');
    $this->db->from('table_autor');
    $this->db->join('table_book', 'table_autor.id_autor = table_book.id_autor', left);
    if($id_book != null){
        $this->db->where('table_book.id_book', $id_book);
    }
    
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if ($this->db->error()) {
        $error = $this->db->error();
        echo 'Error: '. $error['message'];
    }

    echo '</br>';
    echo $this->db->last_query();

    return $result;
}
```